# Given a hyperbolic triangle's sides (or angles), is there an easy way to determine whether it is inscribed in a circle, horocycle, or hypercycle?

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

If I have a hyperbolic triangle, specified by edge lengths or angles, is there an easy way to determine whether it is inscribed into a circle, a horocycle, or a hypercycle?

Comment: My go-to online reference for this kind of information is [here](https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/hyperbolic/hyperbolic0.html), despite it being a bit difficult to navigate (and read). Circumcircle considerations are covered [here](https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/hyperbolic/hybrid.html). You might have to hunt around a bit for notation.

Comment: If you were given the vertices instead, as vectors $a,b,c$ on the hyperboloid in $\mathbb R^{2,1}$, then you could just look at the square of the bivector $B=(b-a)\wedge(c-a)$. Circle, horocycle, hypercycle correspond to $B^2<0,\;B^2=0,\;B^2>0$, respectively. And for calculation, $B^2=\big((b-a)\cdot(c-a)\big)^2-(b-a)^2(c-a)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment, drawing on [this source](https://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/hyperbolic/hybrid.html).

For a hyperbolic triangle with sides $a$, $b$, $c$, consider the quantity
$$h := (\overline{a_2}+\overline{b_2}+\overline{c_2})(-\overline{a_2}+\overline{b_2}+\overline{c_2})(\overline{a_2}-\overline{b_2}+\overline{c_2})(\overline{a_2}+\overline{b_2}-\overline{c_2}) \tag{1}$$
where $\overline{x_2} := \sinh(x/2)$ (a notational convention of my own devising). We can write:

> $$\text{A triangle is inscribed in a}\;
> \begin{cases}
> \text{circumcircle} & \text{if}\;h > 0 \\
> \text{horocycle} &\text{if}\;h = 0\\
> \text{hypercycle} &\text{if}\;h < 0
> \end{cases} \tag{$\star$}$$

Note that the circumradius, $r$, is given by
$$\sinh^2 r = \frac{4\,\overline{a_2}^2\,\overline{b_2}^2\,\overline{c_2}^2}{h} \tag{2}$$
a formula that effectively re-confirms $(\star)$: Certainly, a positive $h$ implies a valid (real and finite) $r$; a negative $h$ implies an invalid (imaginary) $r$; and a vanishing $h$ implies an *infinite* $r$.

Comment: I'm curious.  What does a hypercycle look like?

Comment: @OscarLanzi: A [hypercycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercycle_(geometry)) is an "equidistant curve": It's the set of points at a given distance from, and on a given side of, a line.